# How to solve The list of sources could not be read in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, dependencies, 22.04

recently I upgrade from ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 and then in meet this errors
"http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://bh.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details."
please let me know how solve this error.
also my sources list :

```
$ deb-src http://archive.ubuntu..../ubuntu impish main restricted #Added by software-properties

$# See http://help.ubuntu..../community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
$# newer versions of the distribution.
$deb http://archive.ubuntu..../ubuntu impish main restricted
$deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.../ubuntu impish multiverse universe

$## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
$## distribution.
$deb http://archive.ubuntu...../ubuntu impish-updates main restricted
$deb-src http://archive.ubuntu..../ubuntu impish-updates multiverse main restricted $universe

$## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
$## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
$## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
$deb http://archive.ubuntu.../ubuntu impish universe
$deb http://archive.ubuntu.../ubuntu impish-updates universe
$# deb-src http://bh.archive.ubuntu.../ubuntu bionic-updates universe

$## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
$## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
$## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
$## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
$## security team.
$deb http://archive.ubuntu..../ubuntu impish multiverse
$# deb-src http://bh.archive....../ubuntu bionic multiverse
$deb http://archive.ubuntu..../ubuntu impish-updates multiverse
$deb-src http://bh.archive.ubuntu..../ubuntu bionic-updates multiverse

$## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
$## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
$## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
$## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
$## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
$
$## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
$## 'partner' repository.
$## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
$## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.

$deb http://archive....../ubuntu impish-security main restricted
$deb-src http://archive..../ubuntu impish-security multiverse main restricted $universe
$deb http://archive.ubuntu...../ubuntu impish-security universe
$deb-src http://security.ubuntu.../ubuntu bionic-security universe
$deb http://archive.ubuntu.../ubuntu impish-security multiverse
$deb-src http://security.ubuntu.../ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
$deb http://archive.canonical..../ubuntu impish partner
$deb http://security.ubuntu..../ubuntu/ impish-security restricted multiverse main $universe
```

in above source list .com replaced with ...

Comment: The malformed line is in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_archive_canonical_com_-jammy.list` file.